# C++ Callbacks for an Event Manager using std::function and std:bind with derived classes as parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, event-handling, std-function, stdbind

I have the following Event Manager:

**AppEventManager.h**

```
#pragma once

#define GF_BIND_FN(fn) std::bind(&fn, this, std::placeholders::_1)

struct Event
{
public:
    enum EventType
    {
        AppQuit,
        AppBackground,

        WindowResize,
        WindowGainFocus,
        WindowLostFocus

    };

    EventType type = EventType::AppQuit;

    Event(EventType type) : type(type) {}
};

struct WindowResizedEvent : public Event
{
public:
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    WindowResizedEvent(int width, int height) : width(width), height(height), Event(Event::EventType::WindowResize) {}
};

typedef std::function<void(Event&)> Callback;


class AppEventManager
{
public:

    static void AddListener(Event::EventType type, Callback c);

    template <typename T>
    static void TriggerEvent(Event& event);

private:

    static std::map<Event::EventType, std::vector<Callback>> listeners;
};


template<typename T>
inline void AppEventManager::TriggerEvent(Event& event)
{
    std::map<Event::EventType, std::vector<Callback>>::iterator it = listeners.find(event.type);

    if (it != listeners.end())
    {
        for (auto& callback : it->second)
        {
            callback(static_cast<T&>(event));
        }
    }
}
```

**AppEventManager.cpp**

```
#include "AppEventManager.h"

std::map<Event::EventType, std::vector<Callback>> AppEventManager::listeners = std::map<Event::EventType, std::vector<Callback>>();

// Store callback function for each event type
void AppEventManager::AddListener(Event::EventType type, Callback c)
{
    std::map<Event::EventType, std::vector<Callback>>::iterator it = listeners.find(type);

    if (it != listeners.end())
    {
        for (auto& callback : it->second)
        {
            // Check if callback exist
            if (callback.target_type().hash_code() == c.target_type().hash_code())
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    listeners[type].emplace_back(c);
}
```

To add a listener:

```
Window::Window()
{
    AppEventManager::AddListener(Event::EventType::WindowResize, GF_BIND_FN(Window::WindowResized));
}

void Window::WindowResized(Event& event)
{
    if (event.type == Event::EventType::WindowResize)
    {
        WindowResizedEvent e = reinterpret_cast<WindowResizedEvent&>(event);
        windowWidth = e.width;
        windowHeight = e.height;
    }
}
```

To Trigger the Event:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        WindowResizedEvent event(LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam)); <---
        AppEventManager::TriggerEvent<WindowResizedEvent>(event); <---
    }
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code works but as you see in `void Window::WindowResized(Event& event)` I need to cast the Event to the derived WindowResizedEvent.

What I want to achieve is to call `void Window::WindowResized(Event& event)` directly with the WindowResizedEvent parameter: `void Window::WindowResized(WindowResizedEvent & event)` but now it's not possible because `typedef std::function<void(Event&)> Callback;` requires the parameter to be Event and not derived from Event.

I couldn't find other ways to solve this and I don't know if is possible.

If you know a completely different way to achieve this it's also ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have separate vectors for each type. Access them through template functions.

```
class AppEventManager
{
public:

    template <typename T>
    static void AddListener(std::function<void(T&)> callback) {
        get_listeners<T>().push_back(std::move(callback));
    }

    template <typename T>
    static void TriggerEvent(T& event) {
        for (auto& listener : get_listeners<T>()) {
            listener(event);
        }
    }

private:

    template <typename T>
    static std::vector<std::function<void(T&)>>& get_listeners() {
        static std::vector<std::function<void(T&)>> listeners;
        return listeners;
    }
};
```

And used with the type directly instead of an enum.

```
Window::Window()
{
    AppEventManager::AddListener<WindowResizedEvent>(GF_BIND_FN(Window::WindowResized));
}
```

As a side note it's recommended to use lambdas instead of `std::bind`.

```
Window::Window()
{
    AppEventManager::AddListener<WindowResizedEvent>([&](WindowResizedEvent& event) { WindowResized(event); });
}
```

Comment: Works! But I had to replace **<T&>** for **void(T&)** in both `std::function` in **get_listeners()**.
About lambdas, why is better to use them instead of `std::bind`?

Comment: Performance and readability reasons. Also, sometime when using references and `std::bind` you need to use `std::ref` which is not all that intuitive. Lambdas are also very convenient to use when passing a callable to another function, like `std::sort` etc so being consistent and not mixing the two could also be seen as an additional benefit.